# Does ajax asynchronous calls count towards unique page views?

Tags: ajax, asynchronous, seo, slideshow

I am implementing slideshow. I have two options for paging between images:
1) to implement javascript page reload which definitely counts towards unique page view.
2) to implement ajax light box control which i am not sure is unique page view for each image.

I need more information for the second scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How Your ajax request is interpreted by your statistics depends on the configuration of your webserver and / or statistic script installed.

An ajax call is simply a http request, so You can count it or not, depending on the source IP of the request and maybe the user agent (for IP's behind a NAT)

Answer (score 0):

How are you counting pageviews? Google Analytics, for instance, counts page views via JavaScript, so if you don't retrieve and interpret (display to the browser) the GA JavaScript, the load wouldn't be counted.